# Tiling a chessboard

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, tiling, dominoes

Say I have an eleven by eleven chessboard, so there's 121 squares total. I remove the centermost piece so there's 120 pieces. I want to tile the chessboard with 1x4 or 4x1 pieces in a way that none of the pieces I place hang off of the board or overlap with one another. I also want the entire chessboard to be covered. Can it be done? I heard this problem from a friend and looked up a lot of domino tiling theory but can't figure it out still.

Any answers? Even incomplete answers or thoughts would be useful.

Comment: As a general note, this kind of problem just screamed 'coloring proof' at me when I read it. There a different ways to color your board and in general for these kind of problems, either it is relatively straight forward to find a tiling or there is a coloring proof why it is impossible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> no

because

> [image: grid with 2×1 vertical dominoes alternating]
>  Each 1×4 covers exactly two red cells, but there are 61 red cells total.

Comment: Corollary: by applying the same coloring in four ways, we can conclude that there are exactly 4 cells ((4,4) and rotations) that admit such a tiling after removal.

Comment: @Bubbler it only shows that we can't say "no" with this technique, right? Unless, of course, you have an example tiling showing it done with (4,4) removed.

Comment: @justhalf Yes, you're right. Constructing such a tiling is left as an exercise to the reader. :P

Answer (score 4):

A non-coloring solution:

> No, it's impossible (every $v_n$ variable is the number of the vertical blocks starting on row $n$):
>  [image] 
>  11 can be written as $4k+3$ and 10 as $4k+2$, with each horizontal block taking up 4 squares on a row. The rest are vertical blocks. 
>  **Row 1:** $v_1 ≡ 3$ $(mod$ $4)$
> **Row 2:** $v_1 + v_2 ≡ 3$ $(mod$ $4)$
> **Row 3:** $v_1 + v_2 + v_3 ≡ 3$ $(mod$ $4)$
> **Row 4:** $v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + v_4 ≡ 3$ $(mod$ $4)$
> **Row 5:** $v_2 + v_3 + v_4 + v_5 ≡ 3$ $(mod$ $4)$
> **Row 6:** $v_3 + v_4 + v_5 + v_6 ≡ 2$ $(mod$ $4)$
> **Row 7:** $v_4 + v_5 + v_6 + v_7 ≡ 3$ $(mod$ $4)$
> **Row 8:** $v_5 + v_6 + v_7 + v_8 ≡ 3$ $(mod$ $4)$
> **Row 9:** $v_6 + v_7 + v_8 ≡ 3$ $(mod$ $4)$ 
> **Row 10:** $v_7 + v_8 ≡ 3$ $(mod$ $4)$
> **Row 11:** $v_8 ≡ 3$ $(mod$ $4)$
>  This leads to the contradiction where $v_3+v_4+v_5+v_6$ should have been 2 modulo 4 based on the middle row, but is actually divisible by 4.

Taking away a square:

> Let the single square be below the middle row. Then $v_1$ and $v_5$ can be written in the $4k+3$ form. $v_2, v_3, v_4$ and $v_6$ can be written in the $4k$ form. Rows 8 and 9 (from top to bottom) give different results, so it's on Row 8 because its mod 4 sum is 1 lower. Same goes for the column. Row 8, column 8, rotations are welcome.

Comment: Probably correct but not the clearest explanation!

Comment: Sorry, is it clearer now?

Answer (score 2):

A tiling with a different square removed, using @Bubbler's comment:

> [image]
>  The empty square can be moved into any of the three other admissible positions by sliding tiles, as well.